# Arrange the items in a collection randomly on a curve with good orientation in animation node

Tags: animation-nodes, collections

I've been trying to arrange the items in a collection randomly on a curve and  I am blocked.

I would like to dispatch multiples object to create diversity.

This is my differents test.

Blue : Dispatch the same object along curve work perfectly the pilar orientation folow perfectly the curve.

yellow : Dispatch an instance of collection like an oject along a curve work perfectly. The pannel on the picture is maded with multiples object in a collection.

**My problem**

**InPink : Distribute A bunch of object contained in a collection like the Lampposts on the picture. doesn't work.**

Anybody can help me ?

Thanks for your Help

[[image]]

[[image]]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, your instancer object is missing. Also if you use an instancer all objects will be a copy of the same object. Select a couple of objects and press CRTL G, then use a group/collection object node and pass that list to the loop.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz When I have been trying to dispatch multiple object of collection in particles system or matrix with "copy data node" and "get list element Node" It works. But I dont realy understand how i can make the same thing in my loop curve. I put exemple of node tree with object instancer and copy data above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `Random List` and `Copy Object Data` node.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Hari for your help. I post my final node tree above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't replicate the objects in a collection, like a particle system would. You can't use the instancer in a loop and feed it a different object everytime. So you're left with 2 options:

1. Create all the objects beforehand and then distribute them along the
   curve.
2. Use n instancers for n different objects separately. The use combine
   list to get on big list and feed them to the loop.

[image]

Very Important: The object list is a parameter, *not* an iterator.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will trying this